# How do I append lines to the output from a formula summary?

Tags: r

I'd like to append lines from the output of the formula summary.

This is my formula summary--

```
      library(fpp)

      analysisOfVariance <-
        aov(
          score ~ single,
          credit  
        )
        
        summ <- summary(analysisOfVariance)

        # assumes:
        # independent and randomly selected observations
        # normal distributions for each factor level
        # common variance
```

I'd like to add the commented out text to the summary, so that the output looks like this

```
Call:
   aov(formula = as.formula(formula), data = dataset[c(facs$vars[x], 
    nums$vars[y])])

Terms:
                  single Residuals
Sum of Squares    834.84  95658.64
Deg. of Freedom        1       498

Residual standard error: 13.8595
Estimated effects may be unbalanced

        # assumes:
        # independent and randomly selected observations
        # normal distributions for each factor level
        # common variance
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `print.summary.aov` function to include calls to `cat` that print your message at the end. To see the original function, just type this in your console:

```r
stats:::print.summary.aov
```

I found this function because I know that the functions that print results to the console are typically called `print.MODELCLASS`. In your example, calling this:

```r
class(summary(analysisOfVariance))
[1] "summary.aov" "listof"
```

So I knew I was looking for a function called `print.summary.aov`. So I just typed that in the console and found it.

Then modify it as follows:

```r
print.summary.aov <- function (x, digits = max(3L, getOption("digits") - 3L), symbolic.cor = FALSE,
    signif.stars = getOption("show.signif.stars"), ...)
{
    if (length(x) == 1L)
        print(x[[1L]], digits = digits, symbolic.cor = symbolic.cor,
            signif.stars = signif.stars)
    else NextMethod()
    if (nzchar(mess <- naprint(attr(x, "na.action"))))
        cat(mess, "\n", sep = "")
    cat("# assumes:
         # independent and randomly selected observations
         # normal distributions for each factor level
         # common variance\n")
    invisible(x)
}
```

Finally:

```r
library(fpp)
analysisOfVariance <- aov(score ~ single, credit)
summary(analysisOfVariance)

             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value Pr(>F)
single        1    835   834.8   4.346 0.0376 *
Residuals   498  95659   192.1
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# assumes:
# independent and randomly selected observations
# normal distributions for each factor level
# common variance
```

Comment: Can you write about the way you found the print function? I'd like to do the same thing for the `TukeyHSD` function

Comment: I tried the same thing and I got `function (x, which, ordered = FALSE, conf.level = 0.95, ...) 
UseMethod("TukeyHSD")
<bytecode: 0x7f8dcdbfc520>
<environment: namespace:stats>`

Comment: I added a short comment to my post. Let me know if that doesn't work.

Comment: I'm still somewhat confused. I'm trying to find the equivalent for `t.test`

Comment: What is the `class` of the object you want to summarize? Call `class(model)` on it (where model is your actual fitted model).

Comment: It's this class `[1] "htest"` and the model is t.test()

Comment: It looks like this is an object from the `EnvStats` package. So load that package with `library(EnvStats)`, then type `print.htest` in your console to see the content of the function. This is the function that is used to print the results to your console and that you will want to modify.

Comment: Are you sure? I did that, but EnvStats wasn't in my environment even though the t test worked and it gave me the error `Error in space(17) : could not find function "space"`

Comment: I am 100% sure that this is the correct way to modify a printing function, in general, as demonstrated in my answer to the question. However, I am *not* sure that your model object is of a class produced by `EnvStats` package, because you have not supplied a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). It could also be that `space` is not exported by the package, in which case you'll have to modify the function further by calling `EnvStats:::space` (note the three `:::`), which *does* in fact appear to exist.

Comment: Thanks! I added a new quesiton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524093/how-do-i-append-lines-to-the-output-from-a-formula-summary-for-a-t-test

Comment: Can you please updat eyour answer to be more like this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524093/how-do-i-append-lines-to-the-output-from-a-formula-summary-for-a-t-test