# How do I append lines to the output from a formula summary for a t.test()

Tags: r

I want to add details to the summary in the output to the t test function

This is an example

```
library(fpp)
t.test(savings ~ single,
data = credit)
```

I'd like to add rename `95 percent confidence interval:` in the output to `95CI`

I'd also like to make an edit to the `var.test` output

Comment: You cannot change the default output, but you can save the result in a variable and access its parts : `results<- t.test(1:10, y = c(7:20))  ;  results$conf.int  ` etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Use `capture.output`:

```
out <- capture.output(t.test(savings ~ single, credit))
cat(sub("95 percent confidence interval:" , "95CI:", out), sep = "\n")
```

giving:

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  savings by single
t = 1.4651, df = 164.99, p-value = 0.1448
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95CI:
 -0.341452  2.305789
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
           2.761500            1.779332
```

**2)** This would also work but rearranges the output putting the CI last.

```
tt <- t.test(savings ~ single, credit)
replace(tt, "conf.int", NULL); cat("95CI:\n", tt$conf.int, "\n")
```

giving:

```
        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  savings by single
t = 1.4651, df = 164.99, p-value = 0.1448
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
sample estimates:
mean in group FALSE  mean in group TRUE 
           2.761500            1.779332 

95CI:
 -0.341452 2.305789
```

Comment: `out2 <- sub("95 percent confidence interval:" , "95CI:", out)`

Comment: I know that I could use paste() but I don't want to have to run cat again when I do list$onepart

Comment: If `L` is an existing list `L$onepart <- out2` or `L$onepart <- paste(out2, collapse = "\n")` depending on what you want.  `out2` is defined in my last comment.

Comment: Thanks! I put this in a separate question with more context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524490/how-do-i-assign-the-output-of-cat-to-an-object-in-a-list