# How do I assign the output of cat to an object in a list?

Tags: r

From this question, I learned how to replace the [output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64524093/how-do-i-append-lines-to-the-output-from-a-formula-summary-for-a-t-test) from formula summary

I'd like to take my new output and assign it to an object in a list

This is my code

```
library(fpp)

lst <- list()

lst[["partone"]] <-
  cat(
    "ABC",
    gsub(
      "Pr(>F)",
      "p-value",
      capture.output(summary(aov(savings ~ single, data = credit))),
      fixed = T),
  sep = "\n")
```

Unfortunately, instead of saving to the object, it keeps printing

I know that I could use `paste`but I don't want to have to remember to use cat again when I'm working with the output

Comment: I think that `cat` is made to print, so you cant really use it to create objects, you'll have to use paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Capture the output as `out`, insert `ABC` and perform the replacement giving character vector `v`, collapse that to a single newline separated string giving `s`.  Now assign `v` or `s` to the list component as in the question depending on what you want. (Can omit the line creating `s` if `v` is assigned.)

```
out <-  capture.output(summary(aov(savings ~ single, data = credit)))
v <- c("ABC", sub("Pr(>F)", "p-value", out, fixed = TRUE), "\n") # char vec
s <- paste(v, collapse = "\n") # single string
```

The result of `cat(s)` is:

```
ABC
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value p-value  
single        1     94   93.72   3.415 0.0652 .
Residuals   498  13668   27.45                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

### custom class with print method

I am not sure that the added complexity is worth it but if you really want to create an object which displays itself nicely you can create a new class with a custom print method:

```
print.selfcat <- cat
obj <- structure(s, class = "selfcat")
obj  # result is same as for cat(s)
```

### summary.aov subclass

Another possibility is to create a subclass of `summary.aov` class, `summary.aov2` which adds a `name` attribute and a `print` method to wrap  up everything above together:

```
# convert summary.aov class to summary.aov2 class
as.summary.aov2 <- function(x, name = "", ...) {
  structure(x, name = name, class = c("summary.aov2", "summary.aov"))
}

print.summary.aov2 <- function(x, ...) {
  out <-  capture.output(structure(x, class = "summary.aov"))
  v <- c(attr(x, "name"), sub("Pr(>F)", "p-value", out, fixed = TRUE), "\n") 
  s <- paste(v, collapse = "\n")
  cat(s, ...)
}

# test
library(fpp)
modsum <- summary(aov(savings ~ single, data = credit))
modsum2 <- as.summary.aov2(modsum, name = "ABC") # create new object w name
modsum2
```

giving:

```
ABC
             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value p-value  
single        1     94   93.72   3.415 0.0652 .
Residuals   498  13668   27.45                 
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Comment: I get a different output. On my machine it shows `> s
[1] "ABC\n             Df Sum Sq Mean Sq F value p-value  \nsingle        1     94   93.72   3.415 0.0652 .\nResiduals   498  13668   27.45                 \n---\nSignif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1\n\n"
> s`

Comment: This seems the same except you need to use `cat(s)` as in the answer if you want it to look nice.

Comment: Please see the question where I mention `I know that I could use pastebut I don't want to have to remember to use cat again when I'm working with the output`

Comment: See discussion added at end.

Comment: This is so incredibly helpful. If i had points, I'd give a bounty

Answer (score 0):

`Cat` will usually return `null` so your list will still be `empty`. Maybe this is a solution for the problem :

```
library(fpp)

lst <- list()

lst$"partone" <-list(    "ABC", gsub(
      "Pr(>F)",
      "p-value",
      capture.output(summary(aov(savings ~ single, data = credit))),
      fixed = T))
    
print("lst")
lst$"partone"
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you said you don't want to remember to use `cat`, you could create a modified `summary.aov()` function that prints out what you want in the first place, then you can forget about `cat` and `gsub`.

Run `print(summary.aov)`, which will print out a function definition (pretty big one). Copy and paste it into an R file and assign it to a new name, like `my.custom.summary <- function ...` That's a larger function than I should paste here, but in there you'll find the string "Pr(>F)" and you can replace it with "p-value".

A possibly cleaner alternative is a search & replace script that runs at the end when you build your report into its final PDF form, but that depends on your process for doing that.